# Contact Logging Report crash - the table is full

Tags: reports, db-logging

I try to run Contact Logging Report, but I get an error message about there are no data in the logging table (Detailed logging is enabled, in the MySQL tables there are a lot of data, and on the Contact's Activity log tab I can see a lot of entries). The CiviCRM Log Viewer extension gives the following error:

```
[info] $Fatal Error Details = Array
(
    [callback] => Array
        (
            [0] => CRM_Core_Error
            [1] => handle
        )

    [code] => -1
    [message] => DB Error: unknown error
    [mode] => 16
    [debug_info] => INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary SELECT entity_log_civireport.id as log_civicrm_entity_id, 1, entity_log_civireport.log_action as log_civicrm_entity_log_action, 'log_civicrm_contact' as log_civicrm_entity_log_type, entity_log_civireport.log_user_id as log_civicrm_entity_log_user_id, entity_log_civireport.log_date as log_civicrm_entity_log_date, modified_contact_civireport.display_name as log_civicrm_entity_altered_contact, modified_contact_civireport.id as log_civicrm_entity_altered_contact_id, entity_log_civireport.log_conn_id as log_civicrm_entity_log_conn_id, modified_contact_civireport.is_deleted as log_civicrm_entity_is_deleted, altered_by_contact_civireport.display_name as altered_by_contact_display_name  
FROM `c5civicrm_crm`.log_civicrm_contact entity_log_civireport

INNER JOIN civicrm_contact modified_contact_civireport
        ON (entity_log_civireport.id = modified_contact_civireport.id )
LEFT  JOIN civicrm_contact altered_by_contact_civireport
        ON (entity_log_civireport.log_user_id = altered_by_contact_civireport.id) WHERE ( 1 )  AND (entity_log_civireport.log_action != 'Initialization') GROUP BY entity_log_civireport.log_conn_id, entity_log_civireport.log_user_id, EXTRACT(DAY_MICROSECOND FROM entity_log_civireport.log_date), entity_log_civireport.id  ORDER BY entity_log_civireport.log_date DESC  [nativecode=1114 ** The table 'civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary' is full]
    [type] => DB_Error
    [user_info] => INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary SELECT entity_log_civireport.id as log_civicrm_entity_id, 1, entity_log_civireport.log_action as log_civicrm_entity_log_action, 'log_civicrm_contact' as log_civicrm_entity_log_type, entity_log_civireport.log_user_id as log_civicrm_entity_log_user_id, entity_log_civireport.log_date as log_civicrm_entity_log_date, modified_contact_civireport.display_name as log_civicrm_entity_altered_contact, modified_contact_civireport.id as log_civicrm_entity_altered_contact_id, entity_log_civireport.log_conn_id as log_civicrm_entity_log_conn_id, modified_contact_civireport.is_deleted as log_civicrm_entity_is_deleted, altered_by_contact_civireport.display_name as altered_by_contact_display_name  
FROM `c5civicrm_crm`.log_civicrm_contact entity_log_civireport

INNER JOIN civicrm_contact modified_contact_civireport
        ON (entity_log_civireport.id = modified_contact_civireport.id )
LEFT  JOIN civicrm_contact altered_by_contact_civireport
        ON (entity_log_civireport.log_user_id = altered_by_contact_civireport.id) WHERE ( 1 )  AND (entity_log_civireport.log_action != 'Initialization') GROUP BY entity_log_civireport.log_conn_id, entity_log_civireport.log_user_id, EXTRACT(DAY_MICROSECOND FROM entity_log_civireport.log_date), entity_log_civireport.id  ORDER BY entity_log_civireport.log_date DESC  [nativecode=1114 ** The table 'civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary' is full]
    [to_string] => [db_error: message="DB Error: unknown error" code=-1 mode=callback callback=CRM_Core_Error::handle prefix="" info="INSERT IGNORE INTO civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary SELECT entity_log_civireport.id as log_civicrm_entity_id, 1, entity_log_civireport.log_action as log_civicrm_entity_log_action, 'log_civicrm_contact' as log_civicrm_entity_log_type, entity_log_civireport.log_user_id as log_civicrm_entity_log_user_id, entity_log_civireport.log_date as log_civicrm_entity_log_date, modified_contact_civireport.display_name as log_civicrm_entity_altered_contact, modified_contact_civireport.id as log_civicrm_entity_altered_contact_id, entity_log_civireport.log_conn_id as log_civicrm_entity_log_conn_id, modified_contact_civireport.is_deleted as log_civicrm_entity_is_deleted, altered_by_contact_civireport.display_name as altered_by_contact_display_name  
FROM `c5civicrm_crm`.log_civicrm_contact entity_log_civireport

INNER JOIN civicrm_contact modified_contact_civireport
        ON (entity_log_civireport.id = modified_contact_civireport.id )
LEFT  JOIN civicrm_contact altered_by_contact_civireport
        ON (entity_log_civireport.log_user_id = altered_by_contact_civireport.id) WHERE ( 1 )  AND (entity_log_civireport.log_action != 'Initialization') GROUP BY entity_log_civireport.log_conn_id, entity_log_civireport.log_user_id, EXTRACT(DAY_MICROSECOND FROM entity_log_civireport.log_date), entity_log_civireport.id  ORDER BY entity_log_civireport.log_date DESC  [nativecode=1114 ** The table 'civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary' is full]"]
)
```

What's wrong?

Comment: It would be really helpful if you could add your version of Civi and the CMS, just so people know in case they want to try to replicate your issue.

Comment: Sorry. Drupal7, CiviCRM 5.7.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I encountered this today, and it was because my maximum temp table size in MySQL was set too low.  The solution I found (https://stackoverflow.com/a/27830218/2832108) was to edit my `/etc/my.cnf` to increase the values of `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size`.  Assuming you're using `innodb_table_per_file` (and if you aren't you should!) this is likely your problem (unless you ran out of space in your temp directory, in which case that's your problem).

Answer (score 2):

Your message says this several times:

```
[nativecode=1114 ** The table 'civicrm_temp_civireport_logsummary' is full]
```

See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-error-reference.html#error_er_record_file_full